# Firefox keeps showing "Error code: MOZILLA_PKIX_ERROR_V1_CERT_USED_AS_CA"

Tags: firefox, certificate, version, ca

I tried to generate a self signed certificate with SAN to make it possible for my https intercepting proxy to work with firefox the latest version, the problem is that after a lot of trial and error, I got this annoying message:

```
Error code: MOZILLA_PKIX_ERROR_V1_CERT_USED_AS_CA
```

here is its description:

```
An X.509 version 1 certificate that is not a trust anchor was used to issue the server’s certificate. X.509 version 1 certificates are deprecated and should not be used to sign other certificates.
```

I checked that the CA certificate is v3 and the generated server's certificate is v3 too, but firefox keeps showing this message.
Any help is appreciated.

**Update:**

I removed cert9.db, now it is showing this error:

```
MOZILLA_PKIX_ERROR_SELF_SIGNED_CERT
```

I don't know how this is possible since I readded the CA certificate to firefox trust store.
again, any help is appreciated.

Here is how I generated the certificates:

**Generating Certificate Authority:**

```
openssl genrsa -out ca.key 2048
openssl req -new -x509 -days 3650 -key ca.key -out ca.crt -subj "/CN=Proxy CA"
openssl genrsa -out cert.key 2048
```

**Generating Server's Certificate:**

```
openssl req -new -sha256 -key cert.key -config config_file -subj "/CN=hostname" -reqexts SAN -out hostname.csr
openssl x509 -req -extfile v3.ext -in hostname.csr -days 3650 -signkey cert.key -set_serial random_string -out hostname.crt
```

**contents of config_file:**

```
contents of /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
.....
[SAN]
subjectAltName=DNS:hostname
```

**contents of v3.ext:**

```
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid,issuer
basicConstraints=CA:FALSE
keyUsage = digitalSignature, nonRepudiation, keyEncipherment, dataEncipherment
```

Regards

Comment: Could you provide some more details? What are you using to * generate* the certificates? Could you provide the binary certificates (public part only) or maybe a similar one omitting sensitive date like company names etc... ?

Comment: Thank you, I just switched to  Firefox esr, it worked without any problems, but I updated the question with how I generated the certificates maybe it could help someone. Regards